# Awesome WM dialog boxes size

Tags: awesome-wm

Is it a way how to set the size of dialog boxes in Awesome WM? Like "add torrent" in transmission torrent client or "select entry to auto-type" in keepassx. E.g. make them bigger every time they appear.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create rules that match the dialog and set the `geometry` property. See https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.rules.html

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit rusty with Awesome WM, but you can append your rc.lua to detect those kinds of windows with the Awful library. Custom linux desktops always require a bit of trial and error. Have a look at these links, too:

https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.placement.html

https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/classes/client.html

That second one is a bit more general, but I'm certain the dialog-type pop-up box is detectable, and resizable.